# Dynamically download images for offline use in Android

Tags: android, networking

I need a way to download roughly 500 images dynamically, and make them available for offline use. There are no use for there images in other applications, so I would like them to be hidden from the user. I want them to be in the `drawable` folder, except I want the app to put them there.

Is this possible? If not, what is a better option?

Comment: what do you mean "dynamically" download images?

Comment: @Aswin Kumar I mean, the images which are to be downloaded aren't preset in any way. I generate a set of URLs using a set of ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want them to be in the `drawable` folder, except I want the app to put them there. Is this possible?

Assuming that you mean you want them to be drawable resources, that is not possible. Resources are set at compile time and cannot be modified at runtime.

> If not, what is a better option?

If these images are all very tiny -- say, less than 1MB combined -- download them to internal storage (e.g., `getFilesDir()`). Otherwise, download them to external storage (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()`), particularly on Android 1.x/2.x devices, so you do not consume an excessive amount of internal storage.

Comment: Each image is aprox. 10kB, which makes the 500 end up at roughly 5MB, so I guess I'll be using external storage. How would I refer to the images in, let's say, another activity? Thank you, help is really appreciated.

Comment: @MartinHaTh: The same way you refer to them in the first activity, or from any other component. If you mean "how do I load them into an `ImageView`?", then use `BitmapFactory` to load the files into RAM on a background thread into a `Bitmap`, which you then hand to the `ImageView`.